# How can I protect my unpublished work that I've sent to others?

Tags: publications

I am a masters student from India applying for a PhD in the US.

I emailed a potential adviser at Harvard University an unpublished paper I have been working on for some time.

The application in the end did not work out but the adviser was enthusiastic about the paper and said I wasn't admitted due to funding issues.

Now I am a bit worried he may publish part of my work without mentioning me, since the paper is not published.

How likely is this? What actions I can take to protect my work?

Comment: I know it is a continual worry of people that others will steal your ideas. Yet it rarely if ever actually happens. Ideas are a dime a dozen.

Comment: @Jon Custer Actually it's an entire paper that one can modify a bit and publish as is

Comment: Why would they do that? Really, this is not a concern at all.

Comment: I would expect good ethical practice from Harvard faculty. Perhaps, though, you have an opportunity for collaboration, or at least feedback.

Comment: This question is just opinion-based. At the bottom line: It just depends on you and the professor that you are sending your work to him/her. Everything has a bit risk. If you prefer to be **100%** sure, do nothing and don't send anything to any other people, but if you think it just makes your PhD application better, OK, do it. I don't think a professor from Harvard University will steal someone else's work, but you may never know. I can't say the chance is absolute zero but it's really low. Again it depends on you to decide.

Answer (score 2):

> How likely is this? Have you ever heard a Professor of this caliber doing something like that?

This depends on the field -- in some fields people are more worried about being "scooped". It could be anywhere from "unlikely but possible" to "extremely unlikely". Overall it is not a serious concern that you should worry about, but it is a remote possibility that you could consider taking steps to prevent.

In response to some comments, let me add that *blatant plagiarism* (where they publish your writing as it is) is much less likely because that is academic misconduct that could get a professor in real trouble when you present the proof.

On the other hand, *scooping* is where you get the idea from the paper, and do it yourself. It is still academic misconduct, but more difficult to prove and it may go unpunished.

> What actions I can take to protect my work, assuming I need about 6
>   months to have it ready for publication?

The best solution is to publish the draft online. This is common in many fields and becoming common in others. If you publish online, everyone will see that this is your work and you did it first; you have documented proof on the internet.

It could also help to document it in other ways: send the draft to others, and put together some proof that you wrote it, just in case.

Comment: I think this is a misrepresentation. Much closer to the truth would be to say that there is absolutely no chance the person at Harvard would use any of your ideas without providing appropriate credit. The worry is just not realistic.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo It is unlikely but possible. I have heard for example from friends in chemistry that even established professors hold onto ideas and are careful to share for fear of being scooped. The worry for a student (who has no status yet) should be greater.

Comment: My point is that "unlikely but possible" is really a bad representation of reality. It just has no basis in fact. Suggesting it has the potential to distort and damage potential interactions between the student and future colleagues.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo OK, I clarified.

Comment: @Morgan That a tenured professor at an R1 university in the States has taken a paper from an unknown author and plagiarized it and gotten away with it? I am not "trying to claim" it has never happened. I am saying it hasn't.

Comment: @Morgan I would appreciate hearing of examples. It would be sobering.

Answer (score 0):

That professor won’t “scoop” you as there is already a paper trail.

Also, he has his own reputation to consider, in fact he might be useful support to you getting your paper published.

I suggest you should not be worried about that professor but getting your paper published asap just in case someone else has a similar paper “ready to go”...